# jupyter read previous bash cell output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
In [1]: %%bash
        ls

In [2]: print(# previous out of ls #)
```

I want to read the output of the **bash** cell in the following python cell in jupyter

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter is not really designed for this, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31025514) suggests a workaround.